# Error in C# insert statement for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, insert, syntax-error

I am trying to pass an insert statement in a C# Winforms to SQL Server. I keep getting a syntax error that just doesn't make sense to me

> error in syntax near "("

My syntax is perfectly fine, as when I copy and paste into SQL Server Mgmt Studio, the code runs perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

[image: error]

```
try
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " +        intodrop.SelectedText + "(" + colnamedrop.SelectedText.ToString() + "," +
                    colnamedrop2.SelectedText.ToString() + ") " + "VALUES" + " (" + valuebox.Text + ");"))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl", intodrop.SelectedText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colname", colnamedrop.SelectedText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@values", valuebox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colname2", colnamedrop2.SelectedText);

        con.Open();

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception g)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + g.Message);
}
```

Comment: Post your code than an image

Comment: Why are you adding parameters if your query doesn't use them?

Comment: Later revision. Just testing new ways to try to get the code to run and forgot to take them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if SelectedText property returns right values. Try to use Text property instead.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + intodrop.Text + 
"(" + colnamedrop.Text + ',' + colnamedrop2.Text + ") " 
+ "VALUES" + " (" + valuebox.Text + ");")
```

Comment: That got it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: you should visit parameters again , this is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You missed comma between column names when insert sql statement preparing. When printing you have comma and display correctly.

Concatenated sql statement without any inputs validation is widely open for sql injection attacks. Try to use parameter as much as possible.

Comment: I found the error you mentioned, but this still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What is the colum data types you asign for insert columns in your database table ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to insert values to two columns, but you are appending them like this "Col1+Col2", instead of "Col1+','+Col2".

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + intodrop.SelectedText + "(" + colnamedrop.SelectedText.ToString() + ','+
                    colnamedrop2.SelectedText.ToString() + ") " + "VALUES" + " (" + valuebox.Text + ");"))
```

I hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but this still does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First try hard coding your insert value after that change it based on your need. Confirm the column data types are assigned correctly.

```
try 
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Property ( FolioNo,PropertyType) VALUES (001,'WIP')"))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception g)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + g.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should have two texbox for entering your values. If no column names you gray the value of column 1, ditto for column 2.
This allows you not to have to enter quote (do not forget to make an escape quotes

2) use the string.format function for more readability

```
try
{

    //Add columns selected
    List<string> Mycolumns = new List<string>();
    If (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(colnamedrop.Text)) Mycolumns.Add(colnamedrop.Text);
    If (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(colnamedrop2.Text)) Mycolumns.Add(colnamedrop2.Text);

    //Add values selected with escaped quoted and string quoted
    List<string> Myvalues ​​= new List<string>();
    If (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(colvalue1.Text)) Myvalues.Add("'" + colvalue1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
    If (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(colvalue2.Text)) Myvalues.Add("'" + colvalue2.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'");

    //If nothing selected, no action
    if (Mycolumns.Count==0 && Myvalues.Count==0) return;

    //Build query
    String Query = string.Format ( "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", intodrop.Text, string.Join(Mycolumns, ", "), string.Join(Myvalues, ", "));

    //Execute query    
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con ))
    {
        con.Open();

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception g)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + g.Message);
}
```